# Dump of Perforce changelists with files

Tags: perforce

I would like to get a dump of all changelists plus the associated files which were part of those changelists.

p4 changes -t -i -l

gives me a list of the changelists, but the files are not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't particularly care how the output is sorted/formatted, this is as simple as:

```
p4 files -a //...
```

This will give you each revision and its associated changelist, so all the data for each changelist will be there -- if you're already going to be parsing all this data into some other key/value store, that's the simplest approach since all the data will be in a uniform format.

If you want Perforce to do more of the work in collating the data for you by changelist, then I'd do something more like:

```
p4 -Ztag -F @=%change% changes | p4 -x - -F "%change%: %depotFile%%depotRev%" files -a
```

If you want descriptions and diffs you could use `describe` instead of `files`:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %change% changes | p4 -x - describe
```

Comment: with the last command I get a lot of: Invalid changelist number '@=10299'.

Comment: typo'd it, just take the `@=` off the format string in the first part.

Comment: is it possible to get descriptions but not diffs?

Comment: where can I get a p4 manual showing me all these options?  p4 help doesn't give much

Comment: `p4 help changes`, `p4 help describe`, `p4 help files`, and `p4 help usage` cover most of it.  The `-F` option is undoc; see https://web.archive.org/web/20131101013248/http://www.perforce.com/blog/130826/fun-formatting